# Small "oh" notation and integration

Tags: real-analysis, integration

This question crossed my mind while doing an exercise.

Suppose we have a function $F(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x,t)dt$ and you want to check whether it is integrable at $+\infty$. Now you find that $f(x,t) = o(g(t))$, with $\int_0^\infty g(t)dt < +\infty$. Can you say that
$$\int_0^\infty f(x,t)dt = \int_0^\infty o(g(t))dt = o \left( \int_0^\infty g(t)dt \right) < +\infty?$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a mistake that is probably the most common mistake made by people who are still getting used to the small $o$ notation (and is mainly the consequence of a sloppy explanation of the notation):

**The small $o$ notation does not describe *functions*, it describes *sets***

By that, I mean that if you have a function $g$, then $o(g)$ is not a **function**, it is a set containing all functions $f$ for which, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a constat $M$ that $|f(x)| < |g(x)|$ for all $x>M$.

Now, if you have two functions, $f$ and $g$, you cannot say that $f=o(g)$, because $o(g)$ is not a function (and thus cannot be equal to $f$). What you **can** say is that $f\in o(g)$, by which you mean that $f$ drops to $0$ quicker than $g$.

---

That said, I don't really know what you are asking. Do you want to prove that $F(x)$ is defined for every $x$ (which is not true for just any function $f$!), or do you want to prove that the integral $$\int_0^\infty F(x)dx$$ exists?

Comment: Ohhh okay your explanation was way better than everything I read on the $o$ notation. In fact it was to prove that $\Gamma(x) = \int_0^\infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt$ is well defined. In the correction, it was explicitly written that $e^{-t}t^{x-1} = o(e^{-t/2})$. Thus my mistake. I then wondered if I could say that $\Gamma(x) = o \left(\int_0^\infty e^{-t/2}dt \right)$ to conclude that it is integrable near $+\infty$.

Comment: @LaurentHayez Yeah, it's very common for authors to write $f=o(g)$, but when they do, they usually want to say that $f\in o(g)$. The relation they want to convey is not that of equality, since, for example, $0=o(g)$ for any $g$, but you cannot say that $0=o(g)$ and $0=o(g)$, therefore $f=0$. I still don't know what you mean by "integrable near $+\infty$", though.

Comment: I split my integral in two parts, one part from 0 to 1 and the other from 1 to $+\infty$. I wanted to prove that $\int_1^\infty e^t t^{x-1} < +\infty$, and it is not a problem for $\int_1^n$ with $n \in \mathbb N$, but I had to check what was happening at $+\infty$, right?

Comment: @LaurentHayez Ah, now I understand. Yes, you're right. And I can now answer your question: If you can prove that, for all $x$, the function $t\mapsto f(x,t)$ is in $o(g)$, and if $\int_{0}^\infty g(t) dt$ exists, then the function $F(x) = \int_0^\infty f(x,t)dt$ is well defined.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience and nice explanations! Do you happen to have any proof of that? I intuitively understand what happens (it should be a argument similar to that one for example: if $u_n$ is a positive sequence such that $u_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2}$ for all $n$, then $\sum_n u_n < +\infty$) but a formal proof would be nice.

Comment: I have a question. If I have a $o(g(x))$ function $f(x)$, what can be said about its antiderivative and its derivative. Will they have some relationship with $o(x\,g(x))$ etc.?